# Point stabilizer subgroups of permutation groups of order $p^aq^b$?

Tags: group-theory, group-actions, permutation-cycles, orbit-stabilizer

Let $G \leq S_n$ be a permutation group of order $p^a q^b$, where $p$ and $q$ are primes. Here the group $G$ is may or may not be transitive.

The natural action of $G$ on $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ is defined as follows: $\chi:G \times \{1,\ldots,n\} \rightarrow \{1,\ldots,n\}$, $\chi(g,i)=i^g$.

The subgroup Point stabilizer of $i$ is defined as follows: $G_i=\{g \in G \mid  i^g=i\} \leq G$.

**Question:** What are these point stabilizer subgroups $G_i$  of $G$ ?

(That is, are the subgroups $G_i$ well studied?)

Refer this links for the definition of [stabilizer](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Stabilizer.html) and [transitive](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/TransitiveGroup.html#:%7E:text=A%20group%20is%20called%20transitive,is%20transitive.)

Comment: Depends on what $G$ is and how it's in $S_n$, of course.

Comment: They could be any subgroup of $G$.

Comment: I guess the "$x$" in the definition of $G_i$ should read "$g$".

Comment: Okay, I see. Thank you for the information.

Comment: Without thinking too much about it, I'd start investigating the particular case $a=b=1$ and $(q>)p\nmid q-1$, where we know that $G$ is then cyclic.